# Bootstrap 3 sticky footer acting awry

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky-footer

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dw3h0vc7/) with full code.

This is a page with 3 distinct sections: a *header*, some *content* and a *footer*.

---

### Sticky footer is not so sticky

The first issue here is that the (rather tall - but intentionally tall) footer is *supposed* to be a "sticky footer". That is, without any content in between the header and the footer, its supposed to be pinned to the bottom of the page/viewport. Instead, you have to scroll down to get to the bottom of the footer. I want the footer to stay the same height, but be 100% visible (the whole thing, from top to bottom) if there's little-to-no content in the main portion of the page.

**How can I accomplish this?**

---

### Page content is overlapping footer

Then, when you add the following "content" to that code:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Now what happens (see this [adaptation to the original jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dw3h0vc7/1/)) is that the content overlaps the footer. This should never happen. Page content should never overlap the footer; the footer should *always* be below the content section.

**How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: Use the technique from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/sticky-footer.css

Comment: Thanks @cvrebert (+1) - that did the trick, although now my footer is a bit too wide (now it forces the browser to provide a horizontal scroll bar). If you decide to explain why this sticky footer technique works in the form of an answer, I'll happily give you the green check. Thanks again!